# How can we implement Cron Job using sidekiq-cron on heroku for production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, cron, sidekiq-cron

## config/schedule.yml

my_first_job:
  cron: "*/5 * * * *"
  class: "HardWorker"
  queue: hard_worker

second_job:
  cron: "*/30 * * * *" # execute at every 30 minutes
  class: "HardWorker"
  queue: hard_worker_long
  args:
    hard: "stuff"

Answer (score 0):

Have you added a sidekiq initializer that loads the file if it exists.
You can use the `YAML.load`

Example

```rb
# config/initializers/sidekiq.rb
cron_schedule_file = 'config/cron_schedule.yml'

if File.exist?(cron_schedule_file) && Sidekiq.server?
  Sidekiq::Cron::Job.load_from_hash YAML.load_file(cron_schedule_file)
end
```